Связь инлайн и реплай кнопок
Всем привет! Подскажите, возможно ли реализовать в моем коде переход к предыдущему шагу реплай кнопкой "Назад", если в текущем состоянии приходит сообщение от бота с инлайн кнопкой? Использую машину состояний
@rForm.message(Form.ves)
async def form_ves(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    ves = await ves_func(message)
    if ves is None:
        return
    ves = int(ves) if ves.is_integer() else ves
    await state.set_state(Form.berem)
    await message.answer(f'Вы беременны?', reply_markup=Keyboards_Form.berem)


@rForm.callback_query(Form.berem, F.text.lower() == 'назад')
async def back_berem(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.reply("Вы вернулись на предыдущий шаг", reply_markup=Keyboards_Form.menu)
    await state.set_state(Form.ves)
    a1 = 40
    a2 = 99
    value = await randomize(a1, a2)
    await message.answer(f'\nВведите свой вес в кг (если число не целое - введите его с точкой. Например {value}): ')


@rForm.callback_query(Form.berem, F.data == "1")
async def form_berem_yes(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(berem=callback.data)
    await state.set_state(Form.trimestr)
    await callback.message.edit_text(f'Выберете сой триместр беременности:', reply_markup=Keyboards_Form.trimestr)


@rForm.callback_query(Form.berem, F.data == "2")
async def form_berem_no(callback: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(berem=callback.data)
    await state.set_state(Form.boobs)
    await callback.message.edit_text(f'Кормите ли вы грудью?', reply_markup=Keyboards_Form.boobs)

@rForm.message(Form.berem)
async def berem_bad_ans(message: Message):
    await message.reply('Ответьте на вопрос нажатием соответствующей кнопки')

